# Populate data from mySQL using button of aspx instead of hardcode using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I would like to ask if there is a way I can get the data from mySQL where in I will not hard code the "button" list

Example: in  the side bar (the MASTER LIST 1-3)

```
 <%--side bar--%>
   <button class="dropdown-btn">
            MASTER 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <a href="crf_ProfileMaintenance.aspx">MASTER LIST 1</a>
            <a href="crf_UserMaintenance.aspx">MASTER LIST 2</a>
            <a href="#">MASTER LIST 3</a>
        </div>
```